# How to query for pages/post depending on slug?

Tags: php, wp-query, archives, slug

I work on a blog that contains both English and Romanian posts.

I made the site bilingual by prefixing the slug of every article with ro- and en-. It is a simple way and it works pretty well.

Now I have to create a custom archive that displays for a given month, with pagination, just the articles that have a slug (page_name) that begins with ro-, or en- respectively.

I guess I should make two PHP files, one called en-archive.php and other called ro-archive.php, this is what I think I will try, but I do not know how to make the query so that it shows correctly with pagination.

Also, what would be the correct replacement after this change for this:?

```
<ul class='archives-list'><?php wp_get_archives() ?></ul>
```

Thank you.

## Update

I have not tried the accepted answer because I started using a plugin (Polylang) for that but for the community I accepted it (and it looks very nice and is detailed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a custom Page (post type `page`) and a [custom Page Template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use), you can do it like so:

1. In the templates, make a new instance of `WP_Query` which is used for querying the posts in either the Romanian or English language.
2. In the query/function args for `WP_Query` and `wp_get_archives()`, use a custom parameter named `lang` which defines the language slug — `ro` for Romanian, `en` for English — and which is used to include only the posts or the archives having the posts where the post slug *begins with* `<language slug>-`, e.g. `ro-`.

#### The Code

1. **The custom Page template:**

   Note that I used the same code for both the Romanian and English versions, except that the `lang` is of course set to the corresponding language slug. If you want, you can use a custom meta data (e.g. `_lang`) *for the Page* and use just a single template for all languages, but you will need to implement that on your own.

   So on my test site, I've got these Pages:

   - RO Archive (`/ro-archive/`) using the `template-ro-archive.php` template
   - EN Archive (`/en-archive/`) using the `template-en-archive.php` template

   ```php
   <?php
   // I'm only including the main content, but make sure your template contains
   // the Template Name header and the calls to get_header() and get_footer().
   ?>
   <ul>
       <?php wp_get_archives( [
           'lang' => 'ro',
       ] ); ?>
   </ul>

   <?php
   $paged = max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) );

   // Query the posts.
   $query = new WP_Query( [
       'lang'           => 'ro',
       'paged'          => $paged,
       'posts_per_page' => 10,
   ] );

   // Display the loop.
   while ( $query->have_posts() ) :
       $query->the_post();
       // .. your code here.
   endwhile;

   // And a pagination.
   echo paginate_links( [
       'current' => $paged,
       'total'   => $query->max_num_pages,
   ] );

   // Lastly, restore the global $post variable.
   wp_reset_postdata();
   ?>
   ```

   And actually, you can also make the templates [*specific* to the respective Page](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-a-custom-page-template-for-one-specific-page), e.g. use the name `page-ro-archive.php` and not `template-ro-archive.php`.
2. **The query filter for `WP_Query`, using the [`posts_where` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_where):**

   *This code should go in the theme's functions file.*

   ```php
   // Include only the posts where the slug begins with <language-slug>- like ro-
   add_filter( 'posts_where', function ( $where, $query ) {
       if ( ! is_admin() && $lang = $query->get( 'lang' ) ) {
           global $wpdb;
           $where .= $wpdb->prepare(
               " AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_name LIKE %s",
               $lang . '-%'
           );
       }

       return $where;
   }, 10, 2 );
   ```
3. **The query filter for `wp_get_archives()`, using the [`getarchives_where` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/getarchives_where/):**

   *This code should go in the theme's functions file.*

   ```php
   // Include only archives having posts where the slug begins with
   // <language-slug>- like ro-
   add_filter( 'getarchives_where', function ( $where, $parsed_args ) {
       if ( ! is_admin() && ! empty( $parsed_args['lang'] ) ) {
           global $wpdb;
           $where .= $wpdb->prepare(
               " AND post_name LIKE %s",
               $parsed_args['lang'] . '-%'
           );
       }

       return $where;
   }, 10, 2 );
   ```

#### Alternate Solution

Use a *custom taxonomy*, e.g. `lang`, for your articles/posts. That way, you could have the terms `ro` (Romanian) and `en` (English), then you'd have an archive at `/lang/ro` and `/lang/en`. And, you can have a single and standard template (i.e. `taxonomy-lang.php`) for those archives.

But,

1. You'll need to assign all your articles to the correct `lang` term.
2. You'd still need to use the `lang` arg/filter for `wp_get_archives()`.